# Will Installing A Google factory Image Give Me The Ability To Receive OTAs Again

Tags: factory-image

If I restore my Nexus 5x using a Google official factory image, will I receive OTA updates if I don't root afterwards?

Sorry for the previously confusing question.

Comment: Yes... It returns it to out of box factory condition. You can accept OTA updates like normal.

Comment: @acejavelin You should write that as an answer so that Luke can accept it.

Comment: Yes, please!  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes... It returns it to out of box factory condition. You can accept OTA updates like normal.

Be sure to follow the complete flashing instructions using the latest factory images from Google, available [here](https://developers.google.com/android/images). Once this has been completed your phone is essentially "new" and completely stock, and you can accept any OTA or other official updates as you wish.